# Frame pointer + return address

Tags: callstack

Does anybody know where relatively to the frame pointer is the return address of the function?
Is there a difference between windows and unix?

thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't amke much sense to me.  The Frame Pointer register, from my experience, is an offset of some sort from the stack pointer while the return address lives in code space.  Rare is the case that code and stack space mingle.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Michael I think he means, what's the offset on the stack (relative to the frame pointer) where the return address is *stored*? (I agree with you on the "what are you trying to accomplish", though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It strongly depends on the architecture, compiler, etc.

Try dissasembling some toy programs and find out (see [objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) in linux)

Answer (score 1):

The return address is at EBP + 4 in your stack frame but you will not be able to use it like that in a buffer overrun since you do not yet control the flow of execution.

What you should be looking for is the distance of return address from the buffer. That is unique to each vulnerability and anything caught in between will need to be predicted or you will most likely just cause the process to dump.